# C# custom validation for data from a database and how to display these validation warnings

Tags: c#, validation

I read data from a SQL database into a list of objects. The data types of the properties of the entities are all strings. I want to validate these properties and then present the result to the viewer of a website. So for example i have a class like this:

```
public class Customer
{
  public string CustomerNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The CustomerNumber is read from the database as string and i want to validate that it is numeric. There are multiple properties i want to perform custom validations for. How do i approach this the best way? Do i validate it in the backend and send an error list to the front end or do i validate this in the frontend before presenting the data to the user? In the frontend i want the specific property that is not valid to be displayed with a red border for example and an error message for this specific property of the list of objects.

Comment: Instead of making all properties strings, use the correct data type. That inherently has its own validations/restrictions, i.e you can't store a string value in a property of type decimal, int, long, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start would be to use the following. https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/start.html

The validator will build up a list of validation errors based on what you define *is valid*. After you have that list of errors, iterate through that list to build up custom ui controls for the end user